# HTML form reload new database info on submit using JQuery won't work (PHPBB overal_header)

Tags: php, jquery, forms, phpbb

I'm trying to create a webpage which generate most of the site on runtime. To do that I have to use JQuery and included this in the overalheader (I'm using PHPBB) like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I want to use the submit link for a HTML/JS form:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#pagina').val('{menu.BUTTONTEXT}'); $('#input').submit(); return false;">{menu.BUTTONTEXT}</a>
```

(copy from Chrome on runtime, all the values are loaded correctly)

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#buurt').val('buurt 1'); $('#input').submit(); return false;">buurt 1</a>
```

Form:

```
<form id="input" action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="pagina" name="pagina" value="{PAGINA_NAME}"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="buurt" name="buurt" value="{BUURT}"/>
</form>
```

All the vars, generated from the PHP page are working, but when I click on a link Chrome gives me this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined localhost:33
onclick
```

I´m working on Xampp to try this code, but it cannot find the $. Am I doing something wrong or do I have to add a function to define $ as Jquery?

Comment: That probably means jquery isn't loaded for some reason. Are you positive that jquery is loading before you click the button? A quick way to check is to right click in chrome, choose inspect element, click "Network" (or "Resources", or "Console") and reload the page. If the page is failing to load jquery, you will see an error.

Comment: When I look in the Network tab it doesn't show at all...

Comment: I think the Network tab has to be open, then reload the page in the browser and you should see all the html pages, js, images, etc being loaded. Check to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Oh, I see, yeah, if you don't see it at all, then that means it's not getting loaded, which would explain why you're seeing the `$ is not defined`. Maybe try looking in the "Elements" tab (inside the chrome inspector) and double check that jquery script tag is indeed in your header.

Comment: I meant that the jquery.min.js didn't show up in the list in the tab Network. Thanks! I moved the include of JQuery to the html body and it works fine now. Do you have any idea to get it working in the overall_header.html?